# Error while running Java 8 MQ application from WebSphere 8

Tags: java, jms, websphere, ibm-mq

I am getting following error while trying to run a Java 8 MQ application from WebSphere 8:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"
```

After some research I saw some suggestions here that the above error can be resolved by removing all `javax.jms` jars. I have jms-api-2.0 and geronimo-jms_1.1_spec jars in my war file. I removed both of them after which I am seeing the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException
```

This will require JMS jar. Please advise.

Jars packaged in my war:

```
spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.17.RELEASE
spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.17.RELEASE
spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:1.5.17.RELEASE
spring-boot-starter-activemq:jar:1.5.17.RELEASE
commons-lang3:jar:3.5
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.1.11
cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.1.11
cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:3.1.11
wss4j-ws-security-common:jar:2.2.1
groovy:jar:2.4.11
gson:jar:2.8.5
spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:1.5.17.RELEASE
com.ibm.mq:jar:8.0.0.5
com.ibm.mq.headers:jar:8.0.0.5
com.ibm.mq.pcf:jar:8.0.0.5
com.ibm.mqjms:jar:8.0.0.5
com.ibm.mq.connector:jar:7.5.0.5
dhbcore:jar:7.5.0.5
mqcontext:jar:2.3
com.ibm.mq.commonservices:jar:8.0.0.5
jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11
jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11
spring-oxm:jar:4.3.20.RELEASE
```

List of new jars in my war file after removing all com.ibm jars and adding, com.ibm.mq.allclient and jms jars:

```
spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.17.RELEASE
spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.17.RELEASE
spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:1.5.17.RELEASE
spring-boot-starter-activemq:jar:1.5.17.RELEASE
commons-lang3:jar:3.5
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.1.11
cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.1.11
cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:3.1.11
wss4j-ws-security-common:jar:2.2.1
groovy:jar:2.4.11
gson:jar:2.8.5
spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:1.5.17.RELEASE
jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11
jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11
spring-oxm:jar:4.3.20.RELEASE
javax.jms-api:jar:2.0
com.ibm.mq.allclient:jar:9.1.1.0
```

Comment: Which version of WAS are you running?

Comment: Could you show the code that causes the error in your question

Comment: @JoshMc I am running this on WAS 8.5.5.16

Comment: @Morag Hughson I dont think it is the code that is causing this issue. Because code is working fine when run from local (tomcat server).

Comment: It won't work,  WAS v8.5.5.6 comes with MQ RAR v7.1.0.6.  This would itself  include jms 1.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WAS 8.5.5.x does [not support](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rmj_interfaces.html) JMS 2.0:

> WebSphere® Application Server supports applications that use JMS 1.1 domain-independent interfaces (referred to as "common interfaces" in the JMS specification) and JMS 1.0.2 domain-specific interfaces.

You should use the WAS built-in IBM MQ [resource adapter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q132480_.htm) instead of delivering the MQ libraries with your WAR.

Configure the [Queue Connection Factory](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tmj_adm25.html) in the WAS console and follow the [WAS/Spring](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/cspr_data_access_jms.html) guidelines to reference this Connection Factory.

Comment: Nice answer,  thank you for posting the links.   It is also good to quote the important content,  I would suggest adding info from the jms 1.1 support page.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. After removing all JMS and MQ libraries from my war, application is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the IBM MQ "jms.jar" file.  Also, why are you using IBM MQ v8.0.0.5?  It is very out dated.

Rather than mess around with many MQ JAR files, simply use the "com.ibm.mq.allclient" and "jms.jar" JAR files.

To go Maven and use and/or download [IBM MQ v9.1.3.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient) and then also download the [jms.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/javax.jms-api/2.0.1)

Comment: Removed all com.ibm jars and added, com.ibm.mq.allclient and jms jars. Still seeing the same error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory". New list of jars added to question.